# Does NodeMCU support low power mode?

Tags: nodemcu

I'm trying to make a wireless **system that detects if someone is sitting on the toilet or not**.

The idea is using a NodeMCU connected to a wifi-network, updating a database with info about the state of the toiled, "busy" or "not busy".

I would like to know if **NodeMCU supports low power mode via interrupts** so that I could maintain the system with a battery.

Thank you in advance, :)

Comment: You could try using node.dsleep() -->  http://nodemcu.readthedocs.io/en/master/en/modules/node/#nodedsleep

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In low power mode nodemcu cannot be waken up via an internal event. 
You have to trig it externally via a button, a sensor interrupt, etc.

So, I assume that you'll need to use a sensor like PIR for motion detection, if you got a battery friendly sensor, you can wake it up with trigging GPIO16 when it lays in deep sleep.